# HTML5 audio/video tag, duration on Firefox

Tags: html5-audio

I'm building a customized audio player, most of if it done and working fine except for the total duration data that I can't seem to be able to fetch **in Firefox**. I'm using this simple API:

```
var total = audio.duration
```

where audio is the player of course. 
This works fine on chrome and safari apparently, I'm getting the info correctly, but in Firefox it just returns NaN.. 
I tried different ways to select the player, pure JS byId, by tagName, or with jQuery, all return the same...

I can still seek into the song correctly and reach the end which doesn't make sense since the total duration is supposed unknown... O_o

If there are some courageous people with some time on their hands, here's my player object:
[Player Script](http://pastebin.com/Gt0yszLi)

You may try it yourself at [fMusic Player](http://fm.art-of-go.com/)

(little triangle on the right to open the player)

thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated^^

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at pretty much the middle of this:
http://www.protofunc.com/jme/documentation/documentation-faq.html

> The duration of the audio/video is NaN (not a number) and the timeline slider is disabled in 
>   Firefox / Firefox keeps loading, but does not play the audio/video.
>
> Make sure that your server sets the content-length and content-range
>   properties in his response-header.

Maybe it helps?

Comment: yes it helps, but it means I need to know the length on the server side and set it in the head content type... It's all running on nodejs, I'll have to rewrite some stuff :((((

Comment: oops it sends on pressing enter... anyway, thanks a lot, great hint you found here :)